# Can I load my module before other modules

Tags: magento2

Can I load my module before other modules, I want to load my module before module-page-catch how do I do that?

Without changing `app/code/etc/config.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

**Vendor_ComponentA** - your module

**Vendor_ComponentB** - module-page-catch

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ComponentB" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
        <!-- Vendor_ComponentB is dependent on Vendor_ComponentA: -->
            <module name="Vendor_ComponentA" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

or modify the module-page-catch behavior via plugins http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html